# Converting Scala DataFrame column to Seq[Int]

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have a Scala Dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|id   |      measured_value|
+-----+--------------------+
|    0|             1999298|
|    1|              854791|
|    2|             1032910|
|    3|              310905|
|    4|              515442|
|    5|             4176270|
|    6|              807807|
+-----+--------------------+
```

I want to get the column named `measured_value` into a sequence of integers (`Seq[Int]`) and I tried using `df.select("measured_value").rdd.map(r=>r(0)).collect()`. But this gives me `Array[Any]`. How can I convert this into `Seq[Int]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```scala
df.select("measured_value").map(_.getInt(0)).collect.toSeq
```

Some useful examples related to the topic can be found [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5537430417240233/312903576646278/3506802399907740/latest.html).
Please also remember that `collect` leads to collecting all the data on the Spark driver, so in case of a big dataset this may be expensive from the resources perspective.